# dbWriteTable: Error occur if table name is "READ" (reserved word)

Tags: mysql, r, dbi, tibble

I am trying to upload a tibble to mysql server, using function from DBI package in R.

however, I bump into a error if the table name is "READ" or "READs".

```
# an simple table
> x <- tibble(x=rep("a",5))

> dbWriteTable(DB, "READ", x, overwrite = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'READ 
( `x` text 
)' at line 1
```

Successfully upload if change to other names,

```
> dbWriteTable(DB, "READa", x, overwrite = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```

I don't understand what is the syntax error here...

Could someone explain it, please?

Comment: READ is a MySQL reserved keyword. Do [backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23446378/13513328) help?

Comment: Not work. Instead, it create a empty table named "READ". `> dbWriteTable(DB, "\`READ\`", x, overwrite = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: Table 'TEST.\`READ\`' doesn't exist` I think your point about reserved word is right.

Comment: With *backtick* you can use reserved words as name for tables or columns. do `> dbCreateTable(con, "\`READ\`", ...` first and check the result.

Comment: @majidhajibaba Now it works. I create table first `dbCreateTable(DB, "READ", x)` and then append data to it `dbWriteTable(DB, "READ", x, append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)`. If I create table name with _backtick_ through `dbCreateTable`, the table will be named exactly **\`READ\`**.

Answer (score 0):

After searching around, I think this question is duplicated, but I found not concluded answer. So I will post what I tried to solve the problem.

As discussed in the comments, "READ" is a **reserved word** in MySQL. And, backtick does not solve the error in function `dbWriteTable`. Interestingly, "READ" does not prompt an error using `dbCreateTable`.

So the trick is to create table with `dbCreateTable` and then append data with `dbWriteTable`.

Here is the code I tried:

```
dbCreateTable(DB, "READ", table,
               fields = c(Sample_PatientID = "varchar(20)",
                          Sample_Type = "tinyint",
                          Sample_Analytic = "varchar(20)",
                          GeneID = "integer",
                          Value = "decimal(17,10)"))

dbWriteTable(DB, "READ", table, append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)

# fields is for defining datatype, as field.types in dbWriteTable.
```